# Why doesn't the Dutch language pack spellchecker in Outlook 2016 kick in until I have typed in 15-20 words?

Tags: outlook

I use Dutch for all my emails and the English spellchecker is active until I have typed in several words (15 to 20). For example, when I type in: "Ik heb een probleem" (I have a problem), it changes this to: "Ik he been een problem".

The full Dutch language pack is installed, but doesn't kick in immediately and I would like to know why not (and how I can fix this, if possible).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry people - I found the answer myself: File > Options > Language - Dutch was not set as the default spellchecker!